# I'd like to detect device orientation using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android, ios

I want to detect device(iOS or Android) orientation (portrait or landscape) using JavaScript. I used ***window.orientation***. But this API is deprecated written in the following MDN document.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/orientation

So I'd like to know the best way to detect device orientation.

Comment: What exactly do you need to detect?  Do you need the same 0,90,-90,180 values, or is it good enough to simply know landscape or portrait?

Comment: I just need a device landscape or portrait.

Comment: In that case, you could just compare the window height to the window width.

Comment: I solved this problem. I used media queries. This is very useful.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#orientation